# Execute query on remotely multiple database machines

Tags: c#

i am trying to connect multiple databases installed on different machines in my LAN.i am fetching the values of source and users from specific columns of  datagridview.but its not applying query on each machine.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int[] array = new int[i];
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string source = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
    string user = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    int password = Convert.ToInt32(user) + 111;

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source =  " + source + ": 1521/orcl; User id = " + user + "; Password=" + password + ";");
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select ID_STR_RT,ID_WS from tr_rtl where MO_SLS_TOT like '%1%' and DC_DY_BSN='2018-03-01'", conn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dts = new DataTable();

    oda.Fill(dts);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dts;
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: There’s no need to create a new DataTable in the beginning if you’re immediately replacing it with another. Also in your loop you put the datasource as the newly loaded data and then replace it in each iteration so it only shows the last data. Is that the problem? It is a bit unclear what you mean by “not applying query on each machine”

Comment: dear Sami i will try to explain it more,actuly when i click on one button its selecting the data from database and showing in datagridview,and from that datagridview i am take to columns  for source(IP) and user(Database Schema) which have many values and using for loop to make connection to the database for each user and source.but its not executing for all  IPS.sorry if still couldnt make clear .......   :-(

Comment: any body will help me plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz